# Error in sending email and logging to database in 1 request

Tags: php, mysql

I have a piece of code that sends out emails in mass, it gets prepared in a HTML form and passed over to here. This works and sends out the email / redirect to a success page however the part where I want it to log to the database the content of the email just seems to be skipped.

Any advice for this?

```
<?php
// Success Page
$success = header("location: ./success-page");

//Block 1 - Connect to DB 
require("../../../config/mass-mail-connect-db.php");

//Block 2 - Add my own email 
$from= 'help@email.com';

//Block 3 - Passed over 
$subject= $_POST['subject'];
$body= $_POST['body'];

//Block 4 - Connect to DB to retrieve Users
$dbc= mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password, $dbase)
or die("Unable to select database");

//Block 5 - Get the users to send the email 
$query= "SELECT * FROM email_mass_mail WHERE status = 'active'";
$result= mysqli_query ($dbc, $query)
or die ('Error querying database.');

//Insert mass mail into database - ERROR IS HERE AND DOES NOT INSERT
$sql= "INSERT INTO mass_mail_email_history (subject, body)
VALUES ('$subject','$body');";

//Block 6
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$first_name= $row['first_name'];
$last_name= $row['last_name'];
$email= $row['email'];

//Block 7 - Email is sent successfully 
$msg= "$body";
mail($email, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $from);
}
?>
```

Comment: You are preparing `$sql` right above your `while` loop, but you never execute it.

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: `$sql` also is open to SQL injections. Parameterize queries and use prepared statements.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and isn't the best option in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. These give you patterns to follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts and avoids ending up with a confused stew of concerns, with HTML, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and many spots in between.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to `INSERT` history row for each user or for just once to record the operation?

If you need to `INSERT` for each user, `mysqli_query` needs to be called with $sql in while loop.

If you want to `INSERT` it once, `mysqli_query` needs to be called before the while loop with `$sql`.